# Error Building TensorFlow in Julia,

Tags: tensorflow, julia

```
 Error: Error building `TensorFlow`: 
│ ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: is_windows not defined
│ Stacktrace:
│  [1] top-level scope at none:0
│  [2] include at ./boot.jl:317 [inlined]
│  [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1038
│  [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./sysimg.jl:29
│  [5] include(::String) at ./client.jl:388
│  [6] top-level scope at none:0
│ in expression starting at 
/home/amery/.julia/packages/TensorFlow/TizFt/deps/build.jl:13
└ @ Pkg.Operations
```

/buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.0/Pkg/src/Operations.jl:1068

When I build Mocha in Julia,I got is_apple　not defined, some one told me this is because I did not install some module, but which module?

Answer (score 1):

`UndefVarError: is_windows not defined` in practice means that the module has not been updated from Julia 0.6 to Julia 1.0 yet.
As of today I can recommend you to try Julia 0.7 (you will see some deprecation warnings but otherwise it should work) and wait a few weeks before installing Julia 1.0 for use with TensorFlow.jl.

Looking at this thread you can find it should be very soon:
https://github.com/malmaud/TensorFlow.jl/pull/419

Answer (score 0):

This is a sign that the packages haven't updated for v1.0 yet. You either need to help them update their code or wait.